# Change search bar background color in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, button, search, colors

I just want to change the background color of the search bar. It's possible? I just add an attachment so you can see it clearly. The web link is: https://www.formanet.info/. I'm so frustrated with this. Thank you!

Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyp9vzn42be3szu/Captura%20de%20Pantalla%202020-08-28%20a%20la%28s%29%2012.53.54%20a.%C2%A0m..png?dl=0

Comment: Did either answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the class (`.field_search`) so give it a `background-color` and force it to be applied by using `!important`.

```
input.field_search {
    background-color: #b9c4ce !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your CSS file - `/universe_theme/core/css/colors/blue.css`
Line number 44 -

```
.search-form form input {
    background-color: #004074;
}
```